# How can i find threads usage in java using Newrelic?

Tags: java, newrelic

I want to know the **java thread usage** of fixed time [Say 2 days ago, and also **no aggregated results**].
Can i see it using **newrelic** dashboard or even in log files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The New Relic Java agent gets the thread count data using the JMX/MBean system.  This data is then sent to New Relic by the agent once per minute.

Thread count information would not normally be logged to Java agent log file unless logging verbosity had been increased.  (This increased logging verbosity would typically be achieved via changes to settings in the configuration file `newrelic.yml`.)  It would unusual for this information to be in the log file under normal circumstances.

The data stored does become aggregated as it ages depending on what your service level is.  This is described on the docs site page "Data Retention" found here:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/accounts-partnerships/accounts/account-maintenance/apm-data-retention

To summarize, this data is not normally logged but a minute by minute snapshot is available on the JVM metrics dashboard.  You can find out more about the JVM performance details available on that dashboard on the docs site page "JVM Metrics Dashboard" found here:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/monitoring/jvm-metrics-dashboard